# (Ubuntu 20.04) GPU driver version is causing issues, how to downgrade to a previous GPU driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu-driver

(Edit2: solved;

I first used `sudo apt purge nvidia*` and after that `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525 nvidia-dkms-525` it was important to add the nvidia-dkms-525 to the end and it started working after that. Thank you for all who replied!)

I used `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, restarted my pc and now I'm getting weird few seconds freezes in my screen, mouse and programs

Also I'm unable to downscale my screen resolution which I'd done before to increase performance. Currently there is only the "native" resolution available in the menu.

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:08:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001E84sv00001458sd00004008bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU104 [GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER]
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-open - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-515 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

(edit1: `$ nvidia-smi`

`No devices were found`
)

Ubuntu 20.04
Nvidia RTX 2070 Super
AMD ryzen 9 3900X
32 GB

Comment: run `sudo apt purge nvidia*` then restart and reinstall the driver you need

Comment: try reinstalling ubuntu while keeping personal files.

Comment: tip , I always do a clonezilla backup of the partition before doing anything 'radical'. having learnt from the expensive school of experience.

Comment: Thanks for figuring out the solution and posting it. Your's is the only one that worked for me

Comment: Please post the solution in the answer box down below. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question.